# searching unknown activity (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: android, android-manifest, classloader, launching-application

help me to resolve this getting this exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application delhi.roshanara.margapp.MargApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: delhi.roshanara.margapp.MargApp in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/delhi.roshanara.margapp-2.apk]
```

It is searching MargApp Activity to open the project but there is no activity of this name. And I want to start my activity as *.LoginActivity*. Manifest file structure is given below:-

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="MargApp" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OrderMenuPage" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PartyOutstanding" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PartyPDC" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".TakeOrder"></activity>

         <activity
            android:name=".ShowOutstanding"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".ShowPDC"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>

    </application>
```

Comment: what is the package attribute value in manifest tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try removing

```
android:name="MargApp"
```

if that didn't work try Cleaning up your project

Project>Clean

Comment: this will work totally fine. And please mark correct answer so that it could help others.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use the android:name attribute!** It, misleadingly, does not have anything to do with the name of your app and is actually the name of an extra class to load before loading your application. That's why you are getting the `ClassNotFoundException`. Remove it and it should work:

Replace your application tag with this one...

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```